# Layout android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, gesture-recognition, gesturedetector

I would know if there is the possibility to create a new Android Activity with a different layout comparing to linear layout, table layout, relative layout ect...
My goal is to create an activity where the android load some object (for example notes) and place this notes into the activity in order to give the illusion at the final user to have a lot of post-it on the screen of the tablet.

The result that i would to achieve is very similar to the layout of computer, where you have a lot of icons and you can insert, remove and move this icon that represent my notes.
I thougth to use a grid like this http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html, but with this kind of layout can i move where i want my icons??

Comment: @prolink007 if think that you can't know if the answer are useful for me. Maybe if i don't give a +1, maybe are not useful. In the same way, i don't give the -1 when  a person give me an irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to draw your views manually to the screen, probably using something like a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). This will allow you to draw yours views where you like.

Comment: Mimminito but the number of my notes is not fixed, so i would have a procedure to draw a new notes on the screen for each new note??

Comment: This is something you would have to develop. Just have a method, that creates a new note, and renders it to the screen. You should look into how the Android Canvas works, and OpenGL techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private RelativeLayout _mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        _mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        addChild(50, 50, 150, 150, Color.RED);
        addChild(150, 250, 50, 50, Color.GREEN);
        addChild(200, 200, 100, 100, Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void addChild(int centerX, int centerY, int width, int height, int color) {
        int X = centerX - width / 2;
        int Y = centerY - height / 2;

        RelativeLayout child = new RelativeLayout(this);
        child.setBackgroundColor(color);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = X;
        layoutParams.topMargin = Y;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
        child.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        _mainLayout.addView(child);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/canvas"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/bg0large"
        >
</RelativeLayout>
```